# Dutch citizenship through grandparents

Tags: netherlands

Could you help me discover if I have a chance to obtain a Dutch passport?

All four of my grandparents were born in Holland. They immigrated to Canada after WWII. Both of my parents were born in Canada. My mom's parents had naturalized before she was born. My father's mother naturalized after he was born (not sure about his father).

Neither of my parents ever held a Dutch passport, but I was told that my father may in fact have been born with Dutch nationality.

No one can seem to find the true answer tot his question. Would you know? My blood is 100% Dutch, yet it seems weird that I do not have authority to live there.

Comment: Dutch nationality law is pretty aggressive about limiting dual nationality, but it is possible in some circumstances.  In what year was your father born?  In what year were you born?

Comment: My dad was born in Canada in 1955.
I was born in Canada in 1982.

Answer (score 13):

To start with, my knowledge of Dutch nationality law is based on my own research because my circumstances are similar to yours.  My circumstances are not the same as yours, though, and I am not very active in keeping my knowledge up to date, so please take this as a starting point in your own research, and not as a definitive answer to your question.

To summarize, I'm afraid that the answer does not look good for you: You may have been Dutch when you were born, but, if so, you probably lost your Dutch citizenship on 1 April 2013.

To determine definitively whether that is the case, it is critical to determine whether your paternal grandfather ever became Canadian, and, if so, when.  In general, voluntarily acquiring another nationality results in the automatic loss of Dutch nationality.

Your mother's parents most likely lost their Dutch nationality when they naturalized in Canada.  Since they did this before her birth, she did not have Dutch nationality at birth.

If your father's parents were married, then his mother's naturalization is unimportant, as he would only be able to inherit Dutch citizenship from his father.  If his father naturalized before he was born, he would not have been Dutch at birth.  Otherwise, he was Dutch at birth.  If your father's parents were not married, the situation is more complicated, but in such a case he could have inherited his mother's Dutch nationality.

The rest of this assumes that your father was Dutch when he was born.  If he was not, then the following is not relevant.

Under this assumption, the next question is whether your father was *still* Dutch when you were born.  Since he was born in Canada, he did not aquire that citizenship voluntarily, so he was a dual national at birth.  However, since he was born outside the kingdom, under the 1892 nationality law he lost his Dutch citizenship by residing outside the kingdom for ten years after he turned 21.  He was born in 1955, so this happened in 1986, after you were born. (Or, if the ten-year period was reset when the law changed in 1985, he lost his Dutch nationality in 1995; that's still after you were born, of course.)  You were probably therefore Dutch when you were born.

(I also assume that your father never had a Dutch passport or other document showing Dutch nationality; if he did, that would have reset the 10-year clock, and things get fairly complicated in that case, because of the following.)

The provision for dual citizens losing Dutch nationality based on residence outside the kingdom was tweaked a few times, starting in the 1980s.  From 1985, a dual national born in the country of the other nationality would lose Dutch nationality by living for ten years in that country.  The ten years began when the person turned 18.  This would have applied to you when you turned 28 in 2010, except for the fact that this law was changed in 2003.  You were therefore Dutch in 2003, and we need to look at the changed rule.

The 2003 rule provides that a Dutch citizen who holds another nationality and lives anywhere outside the Kingdom of the Netherlands or the EU for an uninterrupted period of ten years loses Dutch nationality.  The ten year period starts on April 1, 2003, or on the 18th birthday, whichever is later.  (The ten year period can be reset, however, by acquiring a passport or other nationality document such as a consular declaration of Dutch nationality.)

You turned 18 in 2000, so your ten year period started on April 1, 2003.  If the assumption about your grandfather is true, and if my analysis concluding that you were Dutch on April 1, 2003 is correct, and if you never got a Dutch passport or lived in the EU or the Carribean Netherlands for a year or longer between 2003 and 2013, then I'm afraid you would have lost your Dutch nationality on April 1, 2013.  (There is another [exception](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7403/dutch-dual-citizens-loss-of-dutch-citizenship?rq=1) that probably doesn't apply: marrying someone who is abroad in the service of the Dutch government or an international organization to which the Netherlands belongs, or being such a person's unmarried partner.)

Finally, there are several ways for former Dutch citizens to regain their Dutch nationality.  Most of the simplified procedures appear not to apply to you, but it seems that if you can get a non-temporary residence permit in the Netherlands for one year, you can apply to regain your Dutch nationality without having to be naturalized.  Follow the links below for more information.

To conclude, as you can see, this is all very complicated.  If you want to be sure not to leave any stone unturned in your effort to become a Dutch citizen, you should probably do the following, and consider working with a Dutch lawyer:

- Determine if and when your paternal grandfather naturalized in Canada
- Read the law yourself to see whether there is some aspect of it that applies to you but which I might have glossed over under the assumption that it is irrelevant
- Apply to the Dutch consulate for a declaration of Dutch nationality, to get an official ruling (rather than relying on this lay analysis)
- If the Dutch authorities find that you are in fact a former Dutch citizen, investigate the options available to you to regain Dutch citizenship.

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_nationality_law
https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijkswet_op_het_Nederlanderschap
http://pvmarkus.home.xs4all.nl/wet.htm

Official information about Dutch nationality and regaining lost Dutch nationality:

https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-nationality/contents/becoming-a-dutch-national
https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/dutch-citizenship
https://ind.nl/EN/Documents/8074.pdf

Comment: Wow!!
This information is so in depth! Thank you so much for looking into it and answering my query. I will have to find out when my grandfather became a naturalized Canadian. My dad nor I ever had Dutch passports and never lived in NL.

I married a British guy 6 years ago and am trying to get my marriage visa - I Just thought (hoped) this may be a quick and easy solution as the British visa process is not easy and I was rejected a year ago.

For some reason I feel like I can plea of case of WWII. My grandfather was a prisoner of war and this is the reason why he left.If the war had never left

Comment: And if he hadn't left I would've been born in Holland.

Comment: @laura If your husband can live in another EU country for six months or more you can move there with him very easily and probably sidestep the British visa problem using the [Surinder Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surinder_Singh_route) route.  That country could be the Netherlands, in which case you might be able to become Dutch more quickly than you otherwise would if you stay there a bit longer.

Comment: @laura as to the WWII angle: if your grandfather hadn't left Holland would he have met your grandmother?  Would your parents have met?  Would you have been born at all?  This kind of reasoning won't get you anywhere in terms of a citizenship application unless there's a specific provision of the law you can capitalize on.  As far as I know, there isn't.

Comment: That is true about the Surinder Singh...but he isn't wanting to go to another EU country as we are trying to put roots down here in UK.

Comment: Yes, my grandfather met and married my grandmother in NL. They immigrated to Canada together with m aunt, who was a baby at the time. The reason I question this is because a friend of mine had a similar war story about his grandfather who was Canadian. And he won the case, granting his Canadian citizenship...which if his grandfather had been in Canada at the time, he wouldn't have been born. But you are right, it is a weak angle.

Comment: @laura that is a cost/benefit calculation you have to make, then.  If the two of you *can* move to another EU country, possibly for as short a period as 6 months, your route to settling in the UK becomes much easier (and cheaper, though you have to weigh that against the cost of the relocation).  Given that you've already been rejected once, it might be worth considering.  If not, you'll just have to exercise extra care in preparing your next application.

Comment: Do you know who I would contact to get the details of the naturalization date of my grandfather into Canada? I called a number of people today and none knew.

Comment: Another question - do you know the required size of accommodation they require for immigration? And, you mention above to exercise extra care in preparing my application - could you elaborate on what this may be?

Comment: @laura if your family does not know, you would have to try the government.  In the US, we had difficulty getting my grandfather's naturalization records until we got help from our congressional representative.  I suppose Canadian MPs may offer similar assistance to their constituents.

Comment: @laura size of accommodation, like how big is the apartment?  I don't know about that.  Extra care in your application: assess why you were rejected and what you can do to avoid that the next time.

Comment: @laura you can look up Canadian naturalization records up to 1951 online.  See http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/immigration/citizenship-naturalization-records/naturalized-records-1915-1951/pages/introduction.aspx.

Comment: You have been unbelievably helpful!!! Who are you? lol

Comment: @laura I am phoog! If you don't investing anything about your rejection for theUK visa to can ask about that here; post a new question.

Comment: @laura I meant to say "I am phoog! If you don't **understand** anything about your rejection for the UK visa, **you** can ask about that here; post a new question."

Comment: @phooog,
You have been unbelievably helpful!!!!!
The link you sent me was fabulous, however, my grandfather was naturalized after 1951. Do you know how I could obtain the records for those who naturalized between 1951 - 1965? I have called lots of places from immigration to the city he went to in Canada and they suggest it is held in Federal Government archives, which are accessible in person or if I hire an investigator. Do you have another suggestion? You have been so helpful, truly amazing! :)

Comment: @laura I suspect that the records after 1951 are not available online because of privacy considerations.  If that is the case then you may be able to find your grandfather's records by applying by mail or in person.  If you go up one level (from the earlier link) to http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/immigration/citizenship-naturalization-records/Pages/introduction.aspx, you will see that you can apply by mail without hiring an investigator if you are Canadian.  You will however need your grandfather's consent, or proof that he died over 20 years ago or was born over 110 years ago.

Comment: hmmmm, well he only died in 2009 (7 years ago) and he would've been 92 this year. So that doesn't apply. Shoot

Comment: @laura and your family no longer has his naturalization papers or other evidence of the date?  It seems like there ought to be an exception to the 20-year rule for family or at least for direct descendants, though I don't see any indication that there is.

Comment: It is tough because my aunt is the executor of the estate and it is all very emotional. It was a HUGE ask to get her to look for it in her box of things. Which it wasn't there. To get her involved in contacting the government etc isn't really possible. I wish this was so much easier! They go on to state that you can hire someone to research for you, but it isn't clear how. I wonder if all of this trouble and hurdles are a sign to give up...

Comment: I have another question for you, Phoog...

Comment: @laura which is?

Comment: So I found out that my grandfather was naturalized after my dad was born - which I suppose means my dad was born with Dutch citizenship...Do you know the best way of going about applying? Do you think I even have a chance?

Comment: @laura sorry, I seem to have missed your last comment.  You can apply at the Dutch consulate that is responsible for the place where you reside.  As I said earlier, I fear your chances are slim, but a determination that you are a former Dutch citizen would make it easier for you to get naturalized if you ever move to the Netherlands (including, I suppose, the Dutch Caribbean).