# Am I eligible for a Dutch passport through my grandfather who is a Dutch citizen?

Tags: citizenship, passport

My Grandfather was born in the Netherlands and was a Dutch citizen until his recent death. He spent most of his life outside the Netherlands but never took up South African citizenship. Will I be eligible for a Dutch passport/citizenship if I work and live in the Netherlands for a couple of years?

Comment: Your grandfather matters less here. I mean sure, if he only had Dutch citizenship then he remained one until his death. But the question is his child, your parent. What citizenship did they have? When? https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7727/dutch-citizenship-through-grandparents is highly relevant to the level of this being possibly a duplicate. Let us know if it is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks .. my dad had a Dutch passport when I was born but unfortunately he never renewed it which is were the problem come in. If I were to have employment in the Netherlands would that possibly help ??

Comment: In most countries if you live there for a set amount of time you can get citizenship, it's just that most countries want some sort of visa that gives you a right to reside and that often comes from employment. But I believe we are trying to decide whether you are already a citizen or not. *Please* read the linked, complex answer.