# Does my mother qualify for a Dutch Passport / Citizenship

Tags: citizenship, netherlands

1. My great grandparents (both Dutch) came to South Africa in 1921.
2. My grandmother was born in Holland in 1916 and came with them at age 5.
3. I discovered a naturalisation certificate (or something like that)    whereby my great grandfather was granted naturalisation on 22 December 1931. It is very faded, but it seems that he also included the names of his children in there. My grandmother was 15 at the time.
4. My grandmother married a South African in 1938.
5. My mother was born in South Africa on 24 August 1939.
6. My grandfather passed away in 1957 and my grandmother remarried a Dutch citizen sometime thereafter.
7. I do remember my grandmother visiting relatives and friends in Holland often, but do not know which passport she used. Sadly she too passed away in 1994.
8. My question is: Does my mom qualify for Dutch citizenship via the Option method?

Comment: Did you look at [this related question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7727/dutch-citizenship-through-grandparents?rq=1) in the sideline (and the references leading from there)?